# Time math in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timer

Noob to javascript and programming in general so I'm a bit stumped on something.

I am wanting to make a simple timer in JS and I have gotten it to work in a really hacky sort of way but I would like to know the "real" way.

I want to make a timer that simply adds X amount of hours and converts hours > 24 to days and also counts down until the timer is done.

So for example if I fed it 48 hours it would display 1 Day, 59 hours, 59 minutes, 30 seconds. ect.. and count down once per second from there.

I have tried this just with empty variables and trying to work out all the time math with conditional logic but it was just too janky/complicated.

I'm now experimenting with getHours and getSeconds but have yet to figure out how to make those count down or anything.

Also, if there are any libraries/js files that help with this sort of thing please let me know. Looking at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) now but I'm still not sure if it can work with just time in the same way I want it to.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or recommendations!

Comment: Moment has support for [durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), but that is secondary to its main functionality.  If you include it just for that, you're adding a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: But as asked, your question is [off-topic because it is asking for a recommendation for a library](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261290/634824), and it is too subjective.  Consider showing the code you wrote that you feel is not ideal, and explain why you think a library might be necessary.